# Jira filter progress field doesn't include sub-tasks estimate

Tags: jira

I have a Jira filter that shows list of tasks. Each task contains a list of sub tasks. I have time estimation for every sub task but not the parent tasks.

When i go to task page I can see it includes time estimation for sub-tasks but when i use filter result widget in my dashboard it doesn't not include sub tasks estimation. (see images below)

[image]

[image]

I want to see remaining estimate and progress based on subtasks of each task. Is there any workaround for this? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

BTW, I prefer to not use any plugins.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have selected the wrong field in your dashboard gadget.you have to select the "Remaining Estimate" with sigma sign as you can see below image.

[image]

I think this will help you :)